# Why is $\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(n/d)=\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Why is
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(n/d)=\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is due to the property that Dirichlet convolutions are commutative

Comment: More generally, $\sum_{d\mid n} f(n/d) = \sum_{d\mid n} f(d)$ for *any* function $f$. Writing out both sides for $n=12$ and $n=16$, for example, should show you why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $d\mapsto n/d$ is a bijection taking the set of divisors of n to itself. So both sides sum over the same terms.